# safari window.open doesn't load contents of page until you click the tab of the window that loaded it

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, typeerror, window.open

I've been trying to get this working correct for some time now...

within a function I have a response text from an ajax call called portinfotext. (it comes from a perl telnet script to run a `sh ip int $interface` on a cisco router.

It is then processed with  `portinfotextbr = portinfotext.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');`

To put these contents in a new window I have

```
var infowin = window.open('', '_blank', 'height=600,width=400,toolbar=0,location=0');
infowin.document.open();

infowin.document.write("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>test</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><BR>"+portinfotextbr+"<BR><CENTER><input type='button' value='Close Window' onclick='window.close()'></CENTER></BODY></HTML>");

infowin.document.close();
```

This code works just fine on my mac using safari.  If I use the iPad it opens a blank tab.  If I click back quickly to the original tab the contents of the second tab will load.  If I wait too long, the blank tab will not load when I click back.

To further complicate matters, if I don't put the var infowin declaration before the ajax call in the function I get the following error ONLY on the IPAD and IPHONE, not on the mac

> TypeError : 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating infowin.document)

Any thoughts?

Comment: right after the `infowin = window.open` line , I added  `alert(infowin);` on the next line.  On the mac running safari it shows [object Window] in the alert box, as well as firefox on ubuntu.  on the iPhone it shows undefined.

Comment: I've changed the code to create a DIV and write the output in.  This was recommended but has not helped the issue

`infowin = window.open('', 'portinfowin', 'height=600,width=400,toolbar=0,location=0');
//alert(infowin);
var objectContainer = infowin.document.createElement("div")
objectContainer.innerHTML ="<BR>"+portinfotextbr+"<BR><CENTER><input type='button' value='Close Window' onclick='window.close()'></CENTER>";
infowin.document.body.appendChild(objectContainer);
infowin.document.close();
`